# XSD abstract type possibly not generated in XML

Tags: xml, xsd, abstract

this is a general XSD validation question.
I'm trying to adapt an XSD schema to an existing XML.
Let's have the following XML branch:

```
<briefing>
   <date/>
   <supplier/>
   <customer/>
   ...
   <q>question 1</q>
   <a>answer 1</a>
   <q>question 2</q>
   <a>answer 2</a>
   ...
</briefing>
```

Now for each briefing I can have 1 customer, 1 supplier and N couples of question and answer: if a want a control over the couple q+a, I should create an element `<qa>` having `maxOccurs=unbounded` and including inside the sequence `<q>+<a>`, each having `minOccurs=maxOccurs=1`.
But what if the `<qa>` element is not available in the XML?
I would like creating an 'abstract' `<qa>` element (or a group), in such a way that the parent abstract element is NOT generated at all, but it's children can still be present with their attributes (sort of *virtual* element).
Anyway neither abstract elements nor groups have been validated in this way and I couldn't find something similar in the specifications...
So finally, what we can say about these kind of elements?
*Is it mandatory that each XSD parent element is present in the finally XML in order to have also its children present inside?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is put the q and a elements under a sequence that has a minOccurs 0 and a maxOccurs set to a value or unbounded on it as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="briefing">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="date" nillable="true" type="xs:date" />
        <xs:element name="supplier" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="customer" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="q" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This will quite happily parse

```
<briefing>
  <date>1999-05-31</date>
  <supplier>supplier_0</supplier>
  <customer>customer_0</customer>
  <q>question 1</q>
  <a>answer 1</a>
  <q>question 2</q>
  <a>answer 2</a>
</briefing>
```

or

```
<briefing>
  <date>1999-05-31</date>
  <supplier>supplier_0</supplier>
  <customer>customer_0</customer>
</briefing>
```

Comment: many thanks! I missed that the sequence could be treated as an unnamed element with min-max occurs properties!